# Passenger not respecting settings

Tags: apache-2.2, phusion-passenger

I have the following settings in my Apache config (not in one of the vhosts but globally):

```
RailsSpawnMethod smart
RailsAppSpawnerIdleTime 0
PassengerMinInstances 2
PassengerMaxPoolSize 5
PassengerPoolIdleTime 120
```

but somehow, each time I access my gitlab subdomain, it takes like forever to load once the idle time is exceeded. Same goes for the startup when using PassengerPreStart directive. As I understood the `PassengerMinInstances 2` should prevent passenger from closing down completely, so there should be 0 waiting time once passenger was loaded and Apache is not restarting.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using passenger 3? Because passenger 2 hasn't this option AFAIR. But there is solution for passenger 2

```
*/5 * * * * curl http://foobar.com
```

in crontab :)

Comment: I'm using passenger 3 `india896:~# passenger --version
Phusion Passenger version 3.0.13`